# Mejorar validación angular y primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

Me gustaria saber si este código se puede mejorar:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-3">
      <label class="blueColorLabel">Name:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <input class="form-control w100" formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="period.name" type="text" minlength="3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls['name'].invalid && (formGroup.controls['name'].dirty || formGroup.controls['name'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
      <span *ngIf="formGroup.controls['name'].errors.required" class="p-inline-message p-inline-message-error">Field is required</span>
      <span *ngIf="formGroup.controls['name'].errors.minlength" class="p-inline-message p-inline-message-error">Must be at least 3 characters long.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

y mi fichero .ts

```
constructor(private periodService: PeriodService, private fb: FormBuilder, private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) {
this.cols = [{ field: 'name', header: 'Name' }, { field: 'eframeDate', header: 'Eframe date' }];
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
  id: [null],
  name: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)] ],
  eframeDate: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)] ]
});    
this.period = { name: '', id: null, periodDate: new Date(), frozenPeriod: false, visible: true, eframeDate: null};
```

}

Imaginemos que tengo 10 inputs de tipo texto, siempre tengo que repetir este div? si no lo pongo no me funciona las validaciones

```
 <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls['name'].invalid && (formGroup.controls['name'].dirty || formGroup.controls['name'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
      //Mensajes a mostrar
  </div>
```

Comment: Podrías crear un componente que reciba como entrada el control e internamente genere los mensajes de error.

Answer (score 0):

Te muestro como haría en tu caso para no repetir tanto.

En tu archivo `component.html` implementaría estos cambios

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="guardarDatos()">
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-3">
      <label for="name" class="blueColorLabel">Name:</label>
      <input id="name" class="form-control w100" formControlName="name" type="text">
      <small  *ngIf="noEsValido('name')">{{getMensaje('name')}}</small>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <button type="submit" label="Guardar"></button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Aquí estarías llamando a dos funciones en tu `component.ts`, una que valida si el campo es válido por los `Validators` que le aplicaste, luego de ser tocada por el usuario y otra que te vuelve el mensaje correspondiente.

```
  noEsValido(campo: string) {
    return this.formGroup.controls[campo].touched && this.formGroup.controls[campo].invalid;
  }

 getMensaje(campo: string): string {
    const error = this.formGroup.get(campo)?.errors;
    let msg:string="";

    if (error?.required) {
      msg='El campo es obligatorio';
    }else if(error?.minLength){
      msg= 'No cumple el minimo de caracteres',
     }
    return msg;
  }
```

En un tu función `guardarDatos()` en tu `component.ts` que es la que utilizaras para enviar tu información al backend, implementas un control para validar a todo tu formgroup y te aparezcan los mensajes correspondientes.

```
guardarDatos(){
if (this.formGroup.invalid) {
      this.miFormulario.markAllAsTouched();
      return;
    }

//desde aqui en adelante realizas el envio de la información del formulario

}
```

Esta acción evita que se envíen los datos sin validar y que muestre todos los mensajes cuando se haga clic sobre el botón enviar

Cuando agregar un nuevo campo al formulario, ejempo `eframeDate`, solo debes cambiar en tu html y quedaria asi

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="guardarDatos()">
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-3">
      <label for="name" class="blueColorLabel">Name:</label>
      <input id="name" class="form-control w100" formControlName="name" type="text">
      <small  *ngIf="noEsValido('name')">{{getMensaje('name')}}</small>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
      <label for="eframeDate" class="blueColorLabel">Name:</label>
      <input id="eframeDate" class="form-control w100" formControlName="eframeDate" type="text">
      <small  *ngIf="noEsValido('eframeDate')">{{getMensaje('eframeDate')}}</small>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button type="submit" label="Guardar"></button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Solo te quedaría personalizar un poco los mensajes en caso de no que querer usar siempre el mismo y darle un toque personal a cada input de tu formulario, lo cual haría de esta manera.

Imaginemos que el mínimo de caracteres sea 3 en uno y 5 en otro y quieras notificar el valor de cada uno de manera diferenciada. Implementaría esta cambio en la función de los mensajes en el error del `minLength`

```
 getMensaje(campo: string): string {
    const error = this.formGroup.get(campo)?.errors;
    let msg:string="";

    if (error?.required) {
      msg='El campo es obligatorio';
    }else if(error?.minLength){
      msg= {
      name:"Debe escribir un mínimo de 3 caracteres",
      eframeDate:"El mínimo de caracteres válido es 5"
      }[campo]|| '';
     }
    return msg;
  }
```